# Does Automapper or Value Injecter use a DI/IOC?

Tags: dependency-injection, automapper, ioc-container, valueinjecter

I haven't used either of these tools but I was wondering if either of them use a DI/IOC or if they are their own DI/IOC or am I missing the point of these tools?

If either of them do use a DI/IOC than what DI/IOC do they use? Basically I am interested in performance.

Comment: They don't depend on any DI framework. How does it relate to performance?

Comment: Ditto, I don't see what DI/IOC has anything to do with performance. All the perf stuff I did (and found) was around reflection optimization and caching.

Comment: For clarity: @JimmyBogard is the developer behind Automapper.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that they don't use a DI/IOC.

Comment: Do eithier of these tools use reflection? And yes a DI/IOC does affect performance by using reflection for runtime weaving.